# What "stability and security will suffer" by using a browser with the --no-sandbox flag?

Tags: web-browser, risk-management, sandbox

Starting Brave browser (on Linux manjaro) shows the message:
`“You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --no-sandbox. Stability and security will suffer.”`

Reading the support forums it seems that one needs to enable user namespaces to get rid of the message. [Brave Support Forum](https://community.brave.com/t/unsupported-command-line-flag-no-sandbox/40069/26)

Questions:

1. What are these "stability and security" risks I'm facing if I ignore the message?
2. Does enabling user namespaces to remove these stability and security risks come with any other security risks?

Comment: Regarding your second question, **yes**, but there's not much you can do about it without using a custom kernel or tweaking sysctl settings. User namespaces, if unprivileged, make privesc vulnerabilities far easier to exploit.

Comment: as far as "stability", it's just that Chrome is not likely to be as well tested with that flag set.  The security part is pretty obvious as you've turned off the browser sandbox which isolates the browser processes and keeps anything coming from the internet inside the sandbox (of the browser).  Without the sandbox a website might access your hard drive and/or run malicious code.